# Filling PDF with AcroForm and XFA form in .NET

Tags: .net, pdf, xfa

I want to fill several PDFs files with AcroForms and XFA forms then save the resulting PDF.

The projet is in vb.NET.

I would like a free solution ideally.

Comment: What exactly are you asking for?

Comment: I have several existing PDF with forms that I want to fill. Some PDF use AcroForm some other use XFA. I want to fill the different fields of the forms and then save the resulting PDF.

Comment: OK. But what have you tried? What stopped you? (And as a warning, XFA is a deprecated, obsoleted technology which is not completely documented publicly. That results in very few non-Adobe options...)

Comment: I have google for library and everything I have not found any free lib. I have tried on lib (Spire.NET) but I found a bug, posted it on there forum. I do have received acknowledgement of the problem with intent fo fix it but with no timeline.
I have no power over the making of the PDF since they are official document made by the administration of my country so I must deal with both XFA and AcroForm or any other things they throw at me.
I hope I have answer your questions.

Comment: I doubt you'll find complete coverage of XFA in any software except Adobe's. Otherwise there are a number of free/inexpensive solutions that allow you to extract the xfa xml, edit it, and put it back in. If you only have to consider a limited set of forms, that might be an option. (Other than that software recommendations are off topic on stack overflow, you might want to ask on [softwarerecs.se].)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You gave me a workaround. Using Spire.NET, I edit the XML of the XFA and then save the PDF and it do the job.
It's quite ugly but it work.
So thank you very much!